# How to derive the $\ nR^2 $ form of the LM test statistic?

Tags: lagrange-multipliers

Several lagrange multiplier (LM) test statistics =$\ nR^2 $~$ \chi^2 $, where the LM test statistic is generated from regressing the square of residuals on some function in an auxiliary equation. The test statistic may only have a$\ \chi^2 $ distribution asymptotically.

White's heteroskedasticity LM test statistic is one example: $\ nR^2 $ is asymptotically $ \chi^2_k $, where k is the number of regressors in the auxiliary equation.

Breusch-Pagan's heteroskedasticity and Breusch-Godfrey's autocorrelation LM test statistics are further examples.

I'm having trouble understanding how this form of the LM test statistic is derived. I've been looking through some of original papers, but I find the derivations difficult to understand. If that's the best there is, I'll have to slog through them. But does anyone have a more concise, easier to understand derivation for any of these LM test statistics? Thanks.

Comment: Hi: I'm not claiming it's easy but the paper by Engle in 1984, titled "Wald, Likelihood Ratio and Lagrange Multiplier Tests in Econometrics" is probably the most detailed explanation out there, atleast as far as I know.  It's available on the net if you google for "lagrange multiplier test in econometrics".

Answer (score 2):

I may be able to offer some reasoning why the LM is calculated as $nR^2$ and has a $\chi^2$ distribution, although it is inherently somewhat technical. The easiest setting to get the general idea of what is happening is using an LM test for variable relevancy. The main theorem used in the derivation is the Frisch-Waugh theorem for partitioned regression and the rest is relatively intuitive given some foundational knowledge of multivariate calculus and statistics. Precise test derivations will be similar, mutatis mutandis.

Suppose we have a model $$y=X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2 +\epsilon$$ where $y$ and $\epsilon$ are $n$ x $1$, $X_1$ is $n$ x $k_1$, $X_2$ is $n$ x $k_2$, $\beta_1$ is $k_1$ x $1$, and $\beta_2$ is $k_2$ x $1$, and we wish to test the hypotheses
$$H_0:\beta_2 =0$$
$$H_1:\beta_2 \neq 0$$

Then we can estimate the model under the null, i.e. $y=X_1 \beta_R +\epsilon_R$, by minimising the sum of squares of the full model whilst imposing the condition that $\beta_2=0$ i.e. we solve $$\min_{b}\{e'e\} \quad \text{subject to} \quad b_2=0$$

To do this we can utilise Lagrange multipliers. We set up the Lagrangian as $$\mathscr{L}(b_1,b_2,\lambda)=e'e +\lambda'b_2$$ This can be expanded as $$\mathscr{L}(b_1,b_2,\lambda)=(y-X_1 b_1-X_2 b_2)'(y-X_1 b_1-X_2 b_2) +\lambda'b_2$$ We then obtain the FOCs: $$\begin{array} ((1) & 0=-2X_1'(y-X_1 b_1-X_2 b_2) \\ (2) & 0=-2X_2'(y-X_1 b_1-X_2 b_2)+\lambda \\ (3) & 0=2b_2 \end{array}$$

We may then obtain from this system the two equations $$X_1'(y-X_1 b_1)=X_1' e_R=0$$ and $$\lambda = X_2'(y-X_1 b_1)=X_2' e_R$$ Now, if we define $M_1=I_n = X_1(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1'$ as the annihilator matrix for $X_1$ then by the Frisch-Waugh-Theorem $e_R=M_1 \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is from the original model, i.e. from $y=X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2 +\epsilon$. Thus, $$\lambda = X_2'e_R=X_2'M_1\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2 X_2'M_1X_2)$$ since we assume $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$ or we may appeal to the Mann-Wald central limit theorem in large samples to obtain a similar asymptotic distribution which will also be normal, albeit with slightly different variance.

Since $rank(X)=k$, $X_2$ has full column rank, as does $M_1$. Thus, $\sigma^2 X_2'M_1X_2 = (\sigma M_1 X_2)'(\sigma M_1 X_2)$ is positive definite, and therefore has an inverse root matrix. So, $$(\sigma^2 X_2'M_1X_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\lambda \sim N(0,I_{k_2})$$. Turning this into a quadratic form we obtain a $\chi^2$ distribution with $k_2$ degrees of freedom: $$\lambda'(\sigma^2 X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1}\lambda \sim \chi^2 (k_2)$$

We still have the issue that there is a $\sigma^2$ here so we may use a consistent estimator of $\sigma^2$ in its stead to get a usable test statistic. For the precise form of the LM of $nR^2$ we use $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{e_R'e_R}{n}$ which is biased but consistent, other estimators for $\sigma^2$ are also usable so long as they are consistent. So our LM statistic is $$\text{LM}=\frac{\lambda'(X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1}\lambda}{e_R'e_R/n}$$.

Now if we run the model $$y=X_1 \beta_R + \epsilon_R$$ and save the residuals $e_R$ we can run the auxiliary regression $$e_R = X\gamma  + \eta$$ where $X=[X_1 \ X_2 ]$. The TSS of the auxiliary regression are $$\text{TSS}=\sum(e_{R,i}-\bar{e}_R)^2=\sum e_{R,i}^2=e_R'e_R$$ where $\bar{e}_R$ is the mean of the restricted residuals and since a constant is assumed to be included in the model, this is zero.

Further, if we consider the predictions of $e_R$ in the auxiliary model then the average of these will also be zero by the same reasoning. So $$\text{ESS} = \hat{e}_R'\hat{e}_R=(X\hat{\gamma})'(X\hat{\gamma})$$ the usual OLS estimator for $\gamma$ is $\hat{\gamma}=(X'X)^{-1}X'e_R$ and so $$\text{ESS} = (X(X'X)^{-1}X'e_R)'(X(X'X)^{-1}X'e_R) = e_R'X(X'X)^{-1}X'e_R$$. Now, by the orthogonality condition between $X_1$ and $e_R$, $X_1'e_R=0$ so $$X'e_R=\begin{bmatrix} X_1' \\ X_2' \end{bmatrix} e_R =\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ X_2' e_R \end{bmatrix}$$ further, by Frisch-Waugh $$(X'X)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \dots & \dots \\ \dots & (X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$$ so $$\text{ESS} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & e_R'X_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \dots & \dots \\ \dots & (X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ X_2' e_R \end{bmatrix}$$ $$\text{ESS} = e_R'X_2(X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1}X_2'e_R$$ thus for the auxiliary regression $$R^2 = \frac{\text{ESS}}{\text{TSS}}=\frac{e_R'X_2(X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1}X_2'e_R}{e_R'e_R}$$ and so $$\text{LM}=n\left[\frac{e_R'X_2(X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1}X_2'e_R}{e_R'e_R}\right]=n R^2\sim \chi^2 (k_2)$$

Comment: Wow. That was a heck of an answer. For a first answer on this list,  you set quite a standard for yourself as far as your future answers. I'll be keeping an eye out. Just out of curiosity, is this type of thing in some econometrics text  because I've never seen anything like it and I have a lot of texts. Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton This derivation follows the method of section 4.2.4 in  Heij et al. (2004) 'Econometric methods with applications in business and economics' Oxford University Press. Oxford. I think Hayashi's Econometrics book covers LM tests as well in section 7.4 for extremum estimators, although the derivations are quite a bit more advanced, and not precisely the same as the one I gave above since it is significantly more generalised. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have Hayashi but not Heij et al. Thanks a lot for the references. They are very useful.